# How to write 2 player chess game with javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I was wondering if there is a nice and easy way to write chess game for the web. I need no AI, no real-time connection to another player, but a table where I can set the figures.

I assume, I have a table 8x8 fields. Now, how could I make an abstract table and put some images on them as figures? Where should I start?

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for? The answer is yes, but you might want to be more specific. Are you looking for source code to a preexisting implementation? General pointers on how to proceed with a new project?

Comment: Yes, something like a tutorial between "Hello World" and "tic-tac-toe". The point would be to use images and to keep the rules of chess. Not that it's a multiplayer engine. Just how to place the images and apply the rules of the game. If source code is given for this, that would be a reveal. Otherwise where to start, I have small experience with programming, but don't want to go deep.

Comment: what is the point really if there is no other player? :/

Comment: The two players sit in front of the same computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heres the first implementation of chess in Javascript:

http://ajax.phpmagazine.net/2006/04/first_implementation_of_a_ches.html

And here is a web page on algorithms needed in a chess game:

http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~tony/ICCA/anatomy.html

Comment: Thanks for the link! Unfortunately, the link given the article (http://chess.labs.morfik.com/) does not work :( But thanks for the tip!

Comment: The algorithms are awesome, though in this small "project" there is no need for any computer skills. I would Vote up if I would have the ability. Just simply kind of drag and drop with the rules of chess.

Comment: +1 I can Vote up now :) Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I create a two player chess game over internet using ajax and php. Simple move logic validated using jquery. other validations and linking users done by php and handled through ajax. You can see the example on this url : http://www.sugunan.com/games/chess/play.php